# Приложение крашится "Unable to instantiate application"

Tags: android

После запуска приложение крашится вот с таким логом

```
Process: ru.aaa.bbb, PID: 28662
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application 
ru.aaa.bbb.AaabbbApplication:
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class 
"ru.aaa.bbb.AaabbbApplication" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/ru.aaa.bbb-1/base.apk"],
nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/ru.aaa.bbb-1/lib/arm64, 
/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
```

Причем на моих девайсах(Реальных и виртуальных) все работает, а у тестеров приложение крашится с этим багом. Прошу вашей помощи.

update_1:Имеется класс AaabbbApplication наследованный от Application, к которому применен паттерн Singleton. В другом месте приложения(Не фрагмент/активити) мне для проверки соединения с инетом нужен был Context, ну я его и стал получать вот таким способом AaabbbApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext(), и собственно после этого у тестеров и начались проблемы с приложением. Но самый интересный вопрос, почему у меня на нескольких реальных и виртуальных девайсах нет этого краха? В чем суть краха?

Comment: Манифест в студию

Comment: раз просите манифест, значит что то подозреваете, что по вашему мнению может быть причиной данной ошибки? какая секция манифеста нужна? Почему приложение крашится не на каждом устройстве?

Comment: Имя пакета приложения и тэг application интересует, и заодно декларацию AaabbbApplication, у вас там что-то с видимость классов напутано.

Answer (score 0):

Совет:

Убейте этот синглтон и передавайте контекст приложения в свои классы через конструктор. В том месте, где вы их создаете, контекст скорее всего присутствует. А если нет, значит и суда нет.

Дополню как ответ, когда увижу, то что просил показать.

Comment: Беспощадное убийство :D